# Too many requests when controlling spinner show/hide from axois interceptors

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have an SPA written in Vue (Webpack) where I want to control the visibility of a spinner based on whether or not the app is currently handling an HTTP request or a response.

Following some tutorials, I came up with the event bus scheme and did this:

Created `eventBus.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const eventBus = new Vue();
```

I'm setting my axios interceptors in the `created()` hook of `App.vue`. Here's what the necessary functions look like in that component:

```
data() {
        return {
            showLoader: false
        };
    },  

    created(){
        this.setAxiosInterceptors();
        // some code removed //            
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        eventBus.$on('show-loader', () => {
            this.showLoader = true;
        });

        eventBus.$on('hide-loader', () => {
            this.showLoader = false;
        });
    },

methods: {       
        setAxiosInterceptors() {
            var tokenCookieName = this.$store.getters.getCookieNames.apiToken;
            var cookieDefaultValue = this.$store.getters.getCookieDefaultValue;

            // token expired middleware
            this.axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
                var data = response.data;

                if(data.info.api_token) {
                    this.$cookie.set(tokenCookieName, data.info.api_token);
                }

                if(data.status == 'error' && data.info.login_failed) {
                    this.$cookie.set(tokenCookieName, cookieDefaultValue);
                    window.location = '/'; // not possible to use Vue router here
                }

                eventBus.$emit('hide-loader');
                return response;
            }, 
                error => {
                    eventBus.$emit('hide-loader');                    
                    console.log('Response interception failed!');
                    return Promise.reject(error);
            });

            // attach API token middleware
            this.axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
                var apiToken = this.$cookie.get(tokenCookieName);

                if (!apiToken) {
                    apiToken = cookieDefaultValue;
                }

                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + apiToken;               
                eventBus.$emit('show-loader');               
                return config;
            }, 
                error => {
                    eventBus.$emit('hide-loader');
                    console.log('Request interception failed!');
                    return Promise.reject(error);                    
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Please ignore some of the code that isn't relevant to the problem, but I wanted to show how things are set up. Problem is, as soon as I visit my home page, the app keep making the startup GET requests over and over, until my server returns a 429 error.

Interestingly, in my `eventBus.$on` handlers, if I just do a `console.log`, this behavior doesn't appear (of course, the spinner doesn't work as well) *but as soon as I change a variable or call a vuex action, this infinite reloading starts*.

Any clue?

Comment: Is `showLoader` used in conjunction with a `v-if`?

Comment: Is the `created` function getting called repeatedly, meaning the component is being destroyed and recreated?

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, `showLoader` is being used to determine `v-if` and `v-else` to conditionally show/hide the spinner. I'm not sure how I can determine if the component is being destroyed repeatedly: if some other factor is causing the browser to reload repeatedly, the `destroyed` function will still be called.

Comment: Try putting your component in [`<keep-alive>`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive) tags.

Comment: @RoyJ You mean wrap my entire `if-else` in `keep-alive` or just the spinner component?

Comment: Just the component that seems to be getting created so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the `main.js` file

```
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create(
  {
    headers:
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  }
);

Vue.prototype.$axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config =>
  {
    eventBus.$emit('show_spin');
    let token = getTokenID();
    if(token && token.length) config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
    return config;
  },
  error =>
  {
    eventBus.$emit('hide_spin');
    if (error.status === 401) VueRouter.push('/login');
    else throw error;
  }
);
Vue.prototype.$axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response =>
  {
    eventBus.$emit('hide_spin');
    return response;
  },
  error =>
  {
    eventBus.$emit('hide_spin');
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
    {
      if (error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401 && !error.config.__isRetry)
      {
        myVue.refreshToken(function()
        {
          error.config.__isRetry = true;
          error.config.headers['Authorization'] = getTokenID();
          myVue.$axios(error.config).then(resolve,reject);
        },function(flag) // true = invalid session, false = something else
        {
          if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') console.log('Could not refresh token');
          if(getUserID()) myVue.showFailed('Could not refresh the Authorization Token');
          reject(flag);
        });
      }
      else throw error;
    });
  }
);

let myVue = new Vue(
{
  el: '#app',
  data: function()
  {
    return {
      spin_visible: 0, // dynamically show/hide spinner
    };
  },
  created: function()
  {
    eventBus.$on('show_spin', this.showSpin);
    eventBus.$on('hide_spin', this.hideSpin);
  },
  methods:
  {
    showSpin: function()
    {
      this.spin_visible++;
    },
    hideSpin: function()
    {
      if(this.spin_visible>0) this.spin_visible--;
    }, 
    ....
```

and then in `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <router-view/>
  <div class="spinner" v-show="$root.spin_visible"> 
  <!-- define your spinner here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hey, could you please explain what the concept is here? I mean, what was I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, the idea is that the counter `spin_visible` is increased before each request and decreased after each request (no matter if it was successful or not). The spinner is shown only if the counter is non-zero. You can not use a Boolean here because if another request is started before the previous one is finished - the first request will reset the boolean variable when it finally completes (while the second request is still active). The code also makes automatic retry if the JWT token has expired.